# Dropdown default to prior set value?

Tags: php, html, query-string

I've got a page with a form that's just a dropdown to show X items per page. It defaults to 5.

```
<form class="rppForm" style="width:110px;" name="reviewsPerPage" method="POST" action="/rpp.php" return false;">
  <select name="reviewsPerPage" style="padding-right: 25px; float: left;">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Okay" name="submit" id="rPP">
</form>
```

This works fine. It sends the information to "rpp.php" and sets a few other variables, then returns to the original page with some variables in the query string, say **www.page.com/?dropdown=15&foo=bar**

Everytime I dynamically adjust the content on the page **?dropdown=15&foo=bar** stays in the query string, but the dropdown shows "5".

Is there away to make the drop down always show the value from the query string by default?

Comment: Would be nice to see what code you're actually using.

Comment: Why do you have a mismatch between the form field name ("reviewsPerPage") and the query string key name ("dropdown")? It would make more sense (and it would be easier to work with) if you used the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<option value="5" <?php if ($_REQUEST["dropdown"] == 5) { echo "selected"; } ?>>5</option>
<option value="10" <?php if ($_REQUEST["dropdown"] == 10) { echo "selected"; } ?>>10</option>
<option value="15" <?php if ($_REQUEST["dropdown"] == 15) { echo "selected"; } ?>>15</option>
<option value="25" <?php if ($_REQUEST["dropdown"] == 25) { echo "selected"; } ?>>25</option>
```